# How to prove that the center of the fundamental group of $T_g$ is trivial for $g \geq 2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Where $T_g$ is a closed orientable surface of genus g.
I want a proof using covering space theory. I know a proof that uses the notion of hyperbolic groups and Riemanian geometry using uniformization theorem. But I want to know is it possible to prove it just using covering space theory?

Comment: There are purely algebraic proofs of this fact, but you need some background in combinatorial group theory, e.g. in Lyndon-Schupp.

Comment: @daw edited....

Comment: Why do you want that? Fundamental groups themselves are generally nontrivial to compute.

Comment: @anomaly I don't care about proofs from covering space theory, but a non-hyperbolic proof as in Moishe's first comment would be nice.

Comment: I do not know how easy it is to show this but provided the center is not $\mathbb{Z}$ there is an easy proof. You can show the commutator is not finite index by appealing to the fact that the sphere and the torus do not cover $T_g$, and in the infinite index case you can use the fact that the fundamental group of a noncompact surfaces is free. Hence, the only possibilities are the trivial group and $\mathbb{Z}$. So we just need to rule out the second case. I would like to say this is possible just by considering automorphisms permuting the generators, but I am not sure.